# combine two file data having same column 1 but different col 2 values

Tags: text-processing, html, join

Need to combine two file data having same column 1 but different column 2 values.

One file has data:

```
AP               3492
BJ               4995
GJ               3810
MH               5800
UK               5148
UP               8096
```

Second file has data

```
AP               3372
BJ               4709
GJ               3728
MH               5403
UK               5154
UP               7724
```

Now want data in below format

```
AP 3492 3372
BJ 4995 4709
GJ 3810 3728
MH 5800 5403
UK 5148 5154
UP 8096 7724
```

Also require the data in html format on mail

Comment: iam working on UNIX system.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `join` command:

```
join -j 1 file1 file2
```

The `-j 1` means to use the first column in each file to match the data. You can also specify e.g. `-1 3 -2 2` meaning "use column 3 from the first file, and match it with column 2 from the second file.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer using **read**. Let's say your files are **a.txt** and **b.txt**. You could do:

```
 while read fp sp; do echo `grep $fp a.txt` $sp  ; done < b.txt
```

Comment: This is slow and inefficient... Use the right tools for this job: `join` or `awk`.